# Error when Displaying Study Results in a Table: 'Row Out of Bounds' Error on Bar 101

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

I'm attempting to display the results of a study in a table format, but I keep encountering an error: 'error on bar 101 : row 1 is out of table bounds. number of rows is 1.' Is there any guidance on how I can address this issue?

Below is the code I'm currently using:

```
// Show the results on the chart
plotshape(condition1, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, title="High Crossing")
plotshape(condition2, location=location.belowbar, color=color.orange, title="Low Crossing")

// Create a table for displaying results
var table myTable = na
if bar_index == 100
    myTable := table.new(position.bottom_left, 3, 1)
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 0, "Condition 1 Hits")
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 0, "Condition 2 Hits")
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 0, "Success Percentage")

if bar_index > 100
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 1, str.tostring(hits1))
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 1, str.tostring(hits2))
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 1, str.tostring(successPercentage) + "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables are 0 indexed. So in your `bar_index > 100` block you are trying to plot in the second row of the table (1), but your table only has 1 row.

Update this line and it should work.

```
myTable := table.new(position.bottom_left, 3, 2)
```